# task restore InterruptionException but cannot catch in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

This is an example of the code I'm using:

```
     class PrimeGenerator implements Runnable{     
     public void run(){
           try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);//a blocking method
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
              System.out.println("interruptedException");
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();//Restore the interrupt
           }
       }
  }
    public class Scheduling{
        private static final ScheduleExecutorService cancelExec = 
             Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        public static void timeRun(final Runnable r,
                                    long timeout,TimeUnit unit)
                                    throws InterruptedException{
        class RethrowableTask implements Runnable{
            @Override
           public void run(){
                 try{
                   r.run();
             }catch(Throwable t){
                  System.out.println("catch"+t);
                  this.t = t;
                }
            }
           }
         }//end RethrowableTask

          RethrowableTask task = new RethrowableTask();
          final Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
          taskThread.start();
          cancelExec.schedule(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                  while(!taskThread.isInterrupted()){
                taskThread.interrupt();//i want taskThread can catch interruptedException
                }
        }
       },1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   } //end timeRun method
 } 

   public class TestPrimeGenerator{
        try{
            Scheduling.timeRun(new Primegenerator(),1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
   }
  }
```

When I run `TestPrimeGenerator`, the `interruptedException` is caught and and printed as `interruptedException`, but the `"catch"+t` is not printed.

Why can't `RethrowableTask` catch the `InterruptionException` which `PrimeGenerator` restored?
please give some help.and appreciate for your any suggestion.

Comment: Please post your real code. What you posted won't compile. And please format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just not how interrupts work. The javadoc says

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), **sleep(long),** or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, **then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.**

So while your `Thread` is blocked in the `sleep()` and receives an `interrupt()`, an `InterruptedException` will occur. In your code, that will be caught in your `PrimeGenerator#run()` `catch` statement. After that, calling `interrupt` on the same `Thread` will do what the javadoc says

> If none of the previous conditions hold then this **thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.**

So no new `InterruptedException` will occur and your `Thread`'s code will continue to execute normally.

Comment: yes  its interrupt status will be cleared,but i restore the interrupted status by calling interrupt on the current thread(in PrimeGenerator catch ),so that code higher up the call stack can see that an interrupt was issued(in RethrowableTask catch),but no

Comment: @user2245634 Sure, its `interrupt` status will be set, but there will be no reason for another `InterruptedException` to be thrown.

Comment: @user Go through the official tutorial on [thread interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: i think another InterruptedException should be thrown,but the reason RethrowableTask#run not catch is there is no method which throws interruptedException(like blocking method)

Comment: @user2245634 Right. Your `Thread` isn't blocked in any of the methods named above, so no `InterruptedException` will be thrown when you try to interrupt it.